# Can I process SSAS tabular partitions in SSIS using the Separate Transactions transaction mode?

Tags: sql-server, ssis, transactions, ssas, tabular

I'm using SQL Server Analysis Services (SSAS) 2019 tabular (1500 compatibility) and I would like to process the model using SQL Server Integration Services (SSIS using Visual Studio 2017 and SQL Server Data Tools SSDT).

I have tried changing the transaction mode to Separate Transactions, but after I click OK it reverts back to One Transaction.  I have also tried this with different providers (OLE DB Provider for Analysis Services 14.0, 13.0, and 11.0), but they all have the same symptom of reverting back to One Transaction.  Incidentally, I'm also unable to choose the Parallel processing order as well.  This also reverts back to Sequential with One Transaction.  Not that I want to use parallel, but I thought I would include this behavior as well.

I have just started using SSAS 2019, I'm used to SSAS 2012 where I could use an XMLA command and part of the command would have the transaction mode in it.

I have tried to look this up online including the TMSL scripting language reference overview ([Tabular Model Scripting Language (TMSL) Reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/analysis-services/tmsl/tabular-model-scripting-language-tmsl-reference?view=asallproducts-allversions)), and I have tried scripting this out from SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS) to look at what options are available there, but I'm not seeing what I'm looking for in either place.  Now I'm wondering if this is even possible in a single Analysis Services Processing Task.  Using the One Transaction mode will roll back any successful partitions in the event of a failure in another partition.

I have partitioned one of the tables by month and I would like the partitions to be in separate transactions in case of failure so that I can target just the unprocessed partitions, or the individual partitions with errors.  I thought about using a For Each Loop to pass the TMSL command dynamically but then I saw the comment by Marco Russo in the comments section of [this post](https://chris.koester.io/index.php/2017/06/21/process-ssas-tabular-tables-partitions-tmsl/) advising against dynamic TMSL.

I would prefer not to have to create twelve Analysis Services Processing Tasks per year, but I will if I have to.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing was using a ForEach loop container to process each partition in a separate transaction.

I set up a Variable Date_Object as datatype Object.  Then wrote a query in an Execute SQL Task to grab a distinct list of the the yearmonth's (e.x. 202005) from my calendar table using the Full Result Set option. Then on the Result Set tab I added a Date_Object in the Variable Name and changed the Result Name to 0.

[Result Set Tab](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WkU0P.png)

Then I connected that to a ForEach loop container.  On the Collection tab I changed the Enumerator to "Foreach ADO Enumerator" and added my Date_Object variable as the ADO object source variable.

[ForEach Loop Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0p1ax.png)

I added a variable called Processing_YearMonth as datatype String.  Then in the ForEach Loop Editor on the Variable Mappings tab I added the Processing_YearMonth variable with an index of 0.

[Variable Mappings](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zhCIX.png)

I added a variable Proc_Cmd_ProcessPartition with a datatype of string.  Then I went into SQL Server Management Studio and connected to my Analysis Services database.  I expanded the cube I wanted to process, then expanded tables, right clicked on the table that I want to process and clicked on Partitions.  Once there I selected one partition and then clicked on the process button.  Which partition doesn't matter because it's going to be parameterized.

[Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZxKhD.png)

I change the mode to "Full" and then clicked the script button.  I'm using Full processing mode here because this is the monthly Full process package.  I have a daily incremental process that processes in the Default mode and for only the three most recent partitions.

[Process Partitions](https://i.stack.imgur.com/HL1cw.png)

This adds a script in a SSMS window, but this script is full of double quotes so the first thing I needed to do was to add a backslash in front of each double quote.

[Script example with old and new](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZbBlQ.png)

I added this script to the Proc_Cmd_ProcessPartition variable replacing the YearMonth portion with the Processing_YearMonth variable.

[Variable Expression](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GwOqC.png)

On my Analysis Services Processing task inside the ForEach Loop Container I opened up the properties and scrolled down to Expressions and added a ProcessingCommands property that included the Proc_Cmd_ProcessPartition variable as the expression.

[Property Expression Editor](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3MqAj.png)

This tells the Analysis Services Processing Task which partition to process and in which mode to process it.